# how to get Rating array of objects in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects:

```
export const Agentdata = [
    {
      Name: 'Jodi M.Heston',
      Gmail: 'jodimheston@inbound.plus',
      Contact: '614-961-3453',
      img: image1,
      Listings: '150 Listings',
      License: '#10491201592',
    },
    {
      Name: 'Danielle C. Whitted',
      Gmail: 'daniellecwhitted@inbound.plus',
      Contact: '702-210-6015',
      img: image2,
      Listings: '140 Listings',
      License: '#10491201542',
    },
  ]
```

I want to implement a rating system for each array of multiple objects and how to get the length of the array in rating:

```
  {
    Agentdata.map((todo) => {
      return (
        <a href="#">
          <div>
            <img src={todo.img} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h5>{todo.Name}</h5>
            <small>{todo.Gmail}</small>
            <small>{todo.Contact}</small>
          </div>
          <Rating name="size-medium" defaultValue={1} value={todo.length} />
        </a>
      )
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Is there a question about an issue buried in there somewhere? Or are you simply requesting someone to write the code for you? Please attempt this on your own first and ask for help if you are stuck on a particular part or have an error/issue. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This way <Rating ... value={Agentdata.length} />

Comment: FYI, it is generally an error to specify both a `defaultValue` *and* `value` prop for "inputs". You ask about get the length of *some* rating array, can you clarify where that array is? You should be able to access the `.length` property from it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the length of `Agentdata` you can use `Agentdata.length` or store it in a variable before writing the `map`.

```
<Rating name="size-medium" defaultValue={1} value={Agentdata.length}/>
```

or

```
const agentLength = Agentdata.length
```

and then inside the `map`, you can use it as follows

```
<Rating name="size-medium" defaultValue={1} value={agentLength}/>
```